# Mystery blind holes on 4 layer boards

Tags: pcb

My workmate designed a 4 layer PCB with blind holes through 1 to 2, 1 to 3,  and 3 to 4 layers due to very confined space.
From my memory, it can't be manufactured.
But the pcb factory managed to make it and all blind vias are connected properly. The board is gold plated. 
And it's very weird all blind vias have no visible holes. What you can see is a gold pad. My mate and I are pulling our hair out(not much left) to figure out how the pcb manufacture made it.

thanks

Comment: Google "blind vias".

Answer (score 3):

Look up "[microvia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microvia)". Various ways to do this, to my knowledge, they usually just drill and plate the inner layers before bonding, instead of the more common bond-and-then-drill.

This will usually result in additional cost and there are limits to what is possible, but it is a well-document technique on HDI PCBs.

Comment: "Microvia" isn't the right term. A "Microvia" is a via smaller than a specified standard. I think what you wanted to say was "Blind via".

Comment: @DerStrom8: Microvia (whatever our view) has become the industry norm term for these especially where the target layers are surface to the next layer.

Comment: @PeterSmith Blind/buried vias are often made using microvia processes (i.e. laser drilling) but a microvia is not necessarily a blind or buried via. They are not one and the same. You can have a microvia that goes through the entire board (not blind or buried)

Answer (score 0):

Horrifically expensive, but a PCB house capable of back drilling for stub removal could probably make that. It is not doable with a normal process flow, but I can see ways to do it if you were prepared to pay.

From the sound of it they have filled and plated the vias, yet more cost, you normally only see that for via in pad on BGA.

I would have expected a standard HDI microvia job to be cheaper!